# Return each name and other field corresponding to maximal value of third field in SQL

Tags: sql

I currently have the table as follows on the picture. 
I would like to write a query which returns all the names and the travel_date with the maximal 'total' value for each name. For example, I would like the query to return in this case: 
Armand 2012-07-18 and Elish 2012-06-18. How could I do that ? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Kindly tag proper DBMS tag.

Comment: `select name, max(travel_date) from the_table group by name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you'll find that the procedure for this is relatively universal. The following example will work in MySQL, MSSQL and DB2 (*among others*).

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    a.travel_date,
    a.total
FROM test_table AS a

INNER JOIN ( SELECT  `name`, MAX(total) AS `total` FROM test_table GROUP BY `name` ) AS b
ON  a.name = b.name
AND a.total = b.total;
```

Here's an example of the sample data I worked with including the results after running the query.
[image: Data example]
**-**
[image: Results]

**Edit:** As  jarlh, the initial query I wrote was indeed wrong. The following query should provide the results that you requested in the comment below.

Comment: I just paid attention that I was not clear and I'm sorry about that. I would like to return each name and the date for which the field total is maximal, and not the maximal value of date. Sorry for the inconvinience... I edited the question

Comment: The first query is invalid.

Comment: Ah yes, you got me. It is absolutely wrong. I'll adjust that. Armand, I have adjusted the query to suit what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, MAX(travel_date)
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY name;
```